# Passing password in encrypted for to SharePoint CSOM model

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://yourserver/")) { context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain"); }

I wand to send this password in encrypted form is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible you can refer following code:

```
var SiteUrl1 = "http://yourwebsite"
var SPUsername1 = "domainName\userName";
var password = "pass";
var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
{
   securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(SiteUrl1);
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(SPUsername1, password);
context.Credentials = credentials;
```